# git flow installer fails to install shFlags on the Mac OS X 10.8.3

Tags: installation, git-flow

Tried this several times including nuking the previous download and manually getting the submodule.  Does anyone have a workaround?

```
SilverFir-2:SRC mike$ sudo ./git-flow-installer 
### gitflow no-make installer ###
Installing git-flow to /usr/local/bin
Cloning repo from GitHub to gitflow
Cloning into 'gitflow'...
remote: Counting objects: 1407, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (602/602), done.
remote: Total 1407 (delta 893), reused 1285 (delta 790)
Receiving objects: 100% (1407/1407), 358.18 KiB | 121 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (893/893), done.
Updating submodules
Submodule 'shFlags' (git://github.com/nvie/shFlags.git) registered for path 'shFlags'
Cloning into 'shFlags'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 204.232.175.90]: errno=Operation timed out

Clone of 'git://github.com/nvie/shFlags.git' into submodule path 'shFlags' failed
install: gitflow/git-flow -> /usr/local/bin/git-flow
install: gitflow/git-flow-init -> /usr/local/bin/git-flow-init
install: gitflow/git-flow-feature -> /usr/local/bin/git-flow-feature
install: gitflow/git-flow-hotfix -> /usr/local/bin/git-flow-hotfix
install: gitflow/git-flow-release -> /usr/local/bin/git-flow-release
install: gitflow/git-flow-support -> /usr/local/bin/git-flow-support
install: gitflow/git-flow-version -> /usr/local/bin/git-flow-version
install: gitflow/gitflow-common -> /usr/local/bin/gitflow-common
install: gitflow/gitflow-shFlags: No such file or directory
SilverFir-2:SRC mike$
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like it may just be a temporary connection issue (though it's unusual that you were able to manually get the submodule but the script couldn't do it). The make-less installer appeared to work fine on my Mac OS 10.8.3 system. The make-less installer isn't doing much, you can run the steps yourself to install it-

```
git clone https://github.com/nvie/gitflow.git
cd gitflow
git submodule init
git submodule update
sudo make install
```

Comment: Before doing `git submodule init` I edited the `.gitmodules` to change shflags location from `git://` to `https://` and that worked for me.

Comment: Great! I made a pull request to fix it.

Comment: Ran git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git:// before git submodule init for same